# asp.net set Session variable and execute a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

net/C# application I have a Link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1"/>
```

When the user clicks this button I want to execute this javascript function:

```
document.getElementById('LinkButtonPrevious').click();
```

And change a Session variable:

```
Session["ID"] = 2;
```

The problem is that the session variable can only be changed in the code behind.

How can I execute both when the link button is clicked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing a value server side requires either a full post of the page or an ajax call.

So you could add a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) and set its value to 2 client side, and then in your server side button handler use that value to set the session variable.

Or you could do an ajax call to a web service.

As far a performing client and server side operations on the same click event, you can do the following. Add a server side Click handler as usual, then register a client side event with [ClientScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registeronsubmitstatement.aspx). Here's the example from MSDN:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csname = "OnSubmitScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the OnSubmit statement is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsOnSubmitStatementRegistered(cstype, csname))
    {
      String cstext = "document.write('Text from OnSubmit statement');";
      cs.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(cstype, csname, cstext);
    }

  }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <title>ClientScriptManager Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form    id="Form1"
            runat="server">
     <input type="submit"
            value="Submit" />
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that. I was asking if both the above functions can be done at the same time when I click a button

Comment: I updated my answer with information on `ClientScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement()`.

Answer (score 1):

You May have to Use ClientCallBack ...

here is an example of it..

[MSDN lINK FOR CLIENT CALLBACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210.aspx)

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function LookUpStock() {
        var lb = document.getElementById("ListBox1"); // this two statements set your javascript
        var product = lb.options[lb.selectedIndex].text;
        CallServer(product, ""); //this method contains code where you set session variable
    }

    function ReceiveServerData(rValue) {
        document.getElementById("ResultsSpan").innerHTML = rValue;
    }
</script>
```